# Change td class with python

Tags: python, html, css

Hi i have Python code that executing sql query. then i put it in html table. I've made css for html td. All i need is to change html TD class with this pyton to change color of td line.

```
#!/opt/nagios/python/bin/python
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

import sys
import errno
import psycopg2

not_needed = ['Ðàäèîïîêðûòèå', 'Êîíòåíò-óñëóãè', 'Ïðîåêò NPS - æàëîáû', 'Ïåðåêëþ÷åíèå ñ Àóòñîðñèíãà']

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="statistic", user="foris-mscp", password="foris-mscp")
cur = conn.cursor()

if len(sys.argv) != 5 or (sys.argv[1] != "all" and not sys.argv[1].isdigit()) or not sys.argv[2].isdigit() or not sys.argv[3].isdigit() or sys.argv[4] not in ["warning", "critical"]:
        print "Wrong or empty argument(s) given"
        sys.exit(2)
else:
        warn_threshold = int(sys.argv[2])
        crit_threshold = int(sys.argv[3])
        current_check = sys.argv[4]

        ex_code = 0
        if current_check == "warning":
                ex_code = 1
                where_statement = "complains_qty >= %s AND complains_qty < %s" % (warn_threshold, crit_threshold)

        elif current_check == "critical":
                ex_code = 2
                where_statement = "complains_qty >= %s" % (crit_threshold)

        if sys.argv[1] == "all":
                #ïðîâåðÿåì âñå æàëîáû
                cur.execute("SELECT subcategory_name, complains_qty FROM cms_data_view WHERE %s AND dt IN (SELECT max(dt) FROM cms_data_view GROUP BY subcategory_id)" % (where_statement))
                if cur.rowcount > 0:
                        result = []
                        for row in cur.fetchall():
                                if(row[0] not in not_needed):
                                        result.append("Ïî óñëóãå '%s' çàôèêñèðîâàíî %s æàëîá" % (row[0], row[1]))

                        if len(result) > 0:
                                print "<br>".join(result)
                                sys.exit(ex_code)
                        else:
                                sys.exit(0)
 else:
                cur.execute("SELECT subcategory_name, complains_qty FROM cms_data_view WHERE subcategory_id     = %s AND %s AND dt IN (SELECT max(dt) FROM cms_data_view GROUP BY subcategory_id)" % (int(sys.argv[1]), where_statement))
                if cur.rowcount > 0:
                        result = []
                        for row in cur.fetchall():
                                result.append("Ïî óñëóãå '%s' çàôèêñèðîâàíî %s æàëîá" % (row[0], row[1]))

                        if len(result) > 0:
                                print "<br>".join(result)
                                sys.exit(ex_code)
                        else:
                                sys.exit(0)
```

I've tried to put it here - `print "<br> <td class="statusWARNING>".join(result)`
 But it's not working.

Comment: Did you put the necessary css styles for that class into your files?

Comment: yes, i've made css style for that class

Answer (score 0):

I think the quotation mark before *statusWARNING* is throwing things off.
Try escaping it with a slash \

```
cur.execute("SELECT subcategory_name, complains_qty FROM cms_data_view WHERE subcategory_id     = %s AND %s AND dt IN (SELECT max(dt) FROM cms_data_view GROUP BY subcategory_id)" % (int(sys.argv[1]), where_statement))
                if cur.rowcount > 0:
                        result = []
                        for row in cur.fetchall():
                                result.append("По услуге '%s' зафиксировано %s жалоб" % (row[0], row[1]))

                        if len(result) > 0:
                                print "<br> <td class=\"statusWARNING>".join(result)
                                sys.exit(ex_code)
                        else:
                                sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: print "<br> <td class=\"statusWARNING\">" this has changed color but created new td , and i need to edit existing

Comment: For that, you'd need to show the code that generated the original (existing) td

Comment: `<td align="LEFT" valign="center" class="statusBGCRITICAL" onclick="window.location.href='http://rip.mts.com.ua/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi?cmd_typ=34&amp;host=Infotel_CMS&amp;service=++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++crit'">Приготовьтесь к предаварийному информированию crit</td>`

Comment: and i need `<td align="LEFT" valign="center" class="statusBGWARNING" onclick="window.location.href='http://rip.mts.com.ua/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi?cmd_typ=34&amp;host=Infotel_CMS&amp;service=++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++crit'">Приготовьтесь к предаварийному информированию crit</td>`

Comment: maybe in Python i need to add align="LEFT" valign="center" not only class?

Comment: You need to modify the bit of python code that generated the original "statusBGCRITICAL" line.  What you are doing now is just appending to it, not replacing it.  But you don't show the bit of code that created statusBGCRITICAL in the first place.

Comment: I've edited question and added all python code. little troubles with encoding. I understand that i'm not replacing it...

Comment: After looking at your code, I think you're trying to create a Nagios plugin. It looks like you're trying to return html in the status information.  But I don't know of any way for you to modify Nagios' display of the status information as it's out of the control of this script.  Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: Nagios dispay all my information correctly, i just need to change this td class...